# How to delete a row from gridview on button click after the row's checkbox is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` created in C# windows forms and `checkboxColumn` added to it. The `DataGridView` is populated with other columns like `Sno`, `AccountNo`, `Name`, `Salary` *(`Sno` is identitycolumn and  primarykey)*.

I want to delete a row *(using stored procedure)* by selecting the `checkbox` and on button click which is out side `DataGridView`. Error at "FindControl".

Stored Procedure:

```
   Create Procedure uspDeleteSelectedRow
   As
       Delete from EmpDetails where Sno=Sno
   Go
```

---

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create String Collection to store IDs of 
        //records to be deleted 
            StringCollection idCollection = new StringCollection();
            string strID = string.Empty;

        //Loop through GridView rows to find checked rows 
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)dataGridView1.Rows[i].
                    Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
            if (chkDelete != null)
            {
                if (chkDelete.Checked)
                {
                    strID = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString();
                    idCollection.Add(strID);
                }
            }
        }
        if (idCollection.Count > 0)
        {
        //Call the method to Delete records 
        DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection);

        // rebind the GridView
        dataGridView1.DataBind();   
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please select any row to delete";
        }

    }

    private void DeleteMultipleRecords(StringCollection idCollection)
    {
        //Create sql Connection and Sql Command
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string IDs = "";

        foreach (string id in idCollection)
        {
            IDs += id.ToString() + ",";
        }

        try
        {
            string test = IDs.Substring
                          (0, IDs.LastIndexOf(","));
            string sql = "Delete from EmpDetails" + " WHERE ID in (" + test + ")";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string errorMsg = "Error in Deletion";
            errorMsg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(errorMsg);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: yes, but did it using without stored procedure.. I want to know how to do it using SP's.. and Im new to sp

Comment: first, just create query for delete and place in your procedure, something like `sp_DeleteStudent(studentId)` and loop the DataGridViewRows `if (selected) then call the sp_DeleteStudent(studentId)`

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz: Im learning stored procedures unable to write the perfect sp for this problem. I can understand that once the checkbox id is selected and assigned that value should be executed using exec ... ..

Comment: @spajce can you explain a bit more in detail

Comment: pleas share your codes on how did you bind your data to `DataGridView` first

Comment: @Sri Then post a question 'How to create a stored procedure that ...' and include the *imperfect* code you wrote so far.

Comment: @spajce can you let me know whats wrong with the code

Comment: If you are having issue with your DataGridView on how to get the selected values then I think you don't need to include your stored proc stuff

Comment: @spajce  
if ((bool)item.Cells[1].Value) .... shows "InvalidCastException was unhandled"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say this is your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ToDeleteEmpDetails] @Sno int
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
AS
    DELETE FROM EmpDetails 
    WHERE Sno = Sno 

    RETURN
```

You don't need a `StringCollection` to delete or call the stored procedure.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            bool IsBool = false;

            if (bool.TryParse(item.Cells[1].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out IsBool)) //<--Where: The ColumnIndex of the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ToDeleteEmpDetails", con))
                    {
                        try {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(); //<--Where: The ColumnIndex of the Primary key from your DataGridView
                            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Cells[0].RowIndex);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        } catch (Exception) {

                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you have some encountered problem from my given answer.

Comment: There's a problem.. all the row's are being deleted at once, after I select any checkbox and pressed the delete button. Also con.open() show exception as "invalidoperationexception was unhandled"

Comment: lets try it again, make sure that columnIndex of`DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` was correct that we try to parse

Comment: I doubt the problem exists in the stored procedure.. i've executed it in SQL Server management studio and saw that all the table rows are being deleted at once.

Comment: are you sure that `sno` is the primary key of `EmpDetails`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. In my code I have class and pass a list of it to gridview as my datasource.

**//Class**

```
public class User
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**//Create a list and bind to the data grid view**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var users = new List<User> { new User { UserName = "Jobert", Selected = false }, new User { UserName = "John", Selected = true }, new User { UserName = "Leah", Selected = true }, new User { UserName = "Anna", Selected = false } };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
    }
```

**//On delete**

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get data back from the source
            var source = dataGridView1.DataSource as List<User>;
            var selectedItems = source.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
            foreach (var item in selectedItems)
            {
                //perform the delete
            }

        }
```